# Phonegap cordova.js not working on android phone

Tags: php, android, html, cordova

Im doing an app with the cordova.js phonegap.

I'm doing it with a external url when it loads

```
super.clearCache();
super.loadUrl("http://EXTERNALURL.COM/");
```

On the index i added this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/statusbarnotification.js"></script>
```

But none of my examples are working, what im doing wrong ?

This is the example code, just to test if PhoneGap was added:

```
    $(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(window.PhoneGap);
        }, 1000);
    });
```

On the PC browser returns a number but on android phone browser:

```
 03-12 15:12:37.279: I/Web Console(1382): undefined at http://EXTERNALURL.COM/:1
```

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap doesn't built for loading external websites, and if you plan to base your app on external urls & launch your it on AppStore, forget it - Apple has really hard-restrictions about this issue.

Please tell us more about your application and what you want to do with your application, maybe we can offer you a better solution which will avoid you from using external pages as your base resources.

Comment: i made it local but still not working ! even $(document).ready ! check here: http://pastebin.com/bxa9PCh5 This is the file redirected from the index.html

Comment: I found the problem, i need to use the onpagecreate ! Consider this solved ! Thanks !